# Want to make a UAV

Tags: wireless, radio, video-transmitter, uav

I've been inspired by the guys at [DIY Drones](http://diydrones.com/) and I'm toying with the idea of making a UAV. To transmit the sensor data, I was thinking I'd go with a 60mW XBee, but I also would like to transmit live video. I'm having a hard time finding a way to transmit live video because I think the XBee will only transmit at low speed. Any idea what camera/transmitter/receiver combo would be possible? I think 1-5 miles range would be ok.

I'm looking for specific products/links.

Comment: Here is a video of people flying such around New York: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9cSxEqKQ78  Maybe not the best place to experiment, but a nice video for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the legal option here would be a 900MHz or 2.4GHz solution.  There are some specialty RC Wireless and Video suppliers like [Hobby Wireless](http://hobbywireless.com/cart/index.php) that carry several different camera/transmitter/receiver solutions.

Remember that it is currently illegal to fly R/C aircraft outside of your line-of-sight (both the AMA and FAA are pretty strict on this).  All model aircraft must remain in the pilot's sight during the entire duration of the flight.  I'm not sure how enforced this is, but you would probably be wise to stay on the legal side of things as you are doing your UAV experiments.

Comment: Here's the legal situation for the UK http://diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/uk-caa-clarify-things

Comment: Ah, yes.  Sorry, I don't know the legal situation worldwide, as I only do things in the states.  The FAA is still pretty nervous about people operating drones in American airspace, so it's best to CYA when doing this type of project.

Comment: This is called FPV and is quite legal in most parts of the world, including the US or UK, regardless of line-of-sight.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm thinking about this one: http://hobbywireless.com/cart/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=404

Answer (score 3):

Legal issues aside, use a separate communication channel for the video stream.  This way it will simplify your hardware and allow you use commercial off the shelf wireless transmitter and receiever the video, and a dedicated control and sensor channel using Xbee (or alternative) communication channel.

Answer (score 2):

Use analog video and a video transmitter/receiver pair.

Total cost less than $50 US.

Comment: Do you have any references for that?

Comment: @reemrevnivek: It's called FPV. Have a look at suppliers like HobbyKing. They have kits including a camera, transmitter and receiver for about $40 US.